# ">" close php tags in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problems using wordpress. I'm editing wordpress page online and using array in it, so when I wrote this on my page,

```
<section id="recent">
    <h1>Recently Added</h1>
    <ul class="row-fluid">
    <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby' =>'date','order' => 'DESC' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
            <li class="span3">    
                    <a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; ?>
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                           <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>
                    </a>
                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>
            </li><!-- /span3 -->
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul><!-- /row-fluid -->
</section><!-- /recent -->
```

The result, is the page is showing this instead what I wished for,

> ‘product’, ‘stock’ => 1, ‘posts_per_page’ => 4, ‘orderby’
>   =>’date’,’order’ => ‘DESC’ ); $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?> ‘; ?>
>   get_price_html(); ?>
>
> post, $product ); ?>

Please help me understand what is happening, and how to solve it.
At least I know that in this part of the codes,

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby' =>'date','order' => 'DESC' );
```

The first '>' symbol, close the php tag

Comment: Unless you have a typo and it's `?>`. A greater than symbol is not a valid php close tag. What is the name of the file it is in?

Comment: The `=>` in the array definition is the first closing `>` in the file, which suggests it has _not_ been sent to the PHP interpreter. If you view the page source in the browser, you will see _all_ the PHP code there.  Are you viewing this with a web server, via `http://localhost`, or attempting to open the file in the browser like `file:///path/to/filename`?

Comment: im editing it on the online host, so maybe it is close to http://localhost, editing it using wordpress editor

Comment: What do you mean editing it using wordpress editor? You want to say you put `php` code in your page in wordpress backend? Because that won't work no matter what you tried. Your code looks ok, but should be in a `.php` file, not in wordpress page. Also don't use `wp_reset_query()`, instead, use `wp_reset_postdata()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use curly braces for the if/else clause in this line:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) { echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); } else { echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; } ?>
```